# Is every oriented edge contained in a unique face?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Let $\Gamma$ be a ribbon graph. The definition of face of $\Gamma$ is given in [Definition 2.2.5., Page 15](https://math.unice.fr/%7Elabourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf)

I feel that the face of a ribbon graph is as follows: If we consider the associated ribbon surface (as Lemma 2.2.4), then it is an open oriented surface. Then to make it closed, we attach discs along it boundary components, i.e., to fill the holes. We say that each disc is a "face". Moreover, the boundaries of this faces will be the boundaries of the disc we will be attaching
at our associated ribbon surface.

But I cannot understand  why it is written that "Note that every oriented edge is contained in a unique face" after the definition 2.2.5.

[image]

If we consider the above figure (clearly it has 7 faces) then the red edge is contained in both the pink and green face. So, why every oriented edge is contained in a unique face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *geometric edge* drawn in red is "intuitively contained" in two faces. However, if we go back to Definition 2.2.1, we see that each such edge is actually made up of two oriented edges: one which starts at the top vertex and ends at the bottom vertex, and one which does the opposite.

Each of these is part of only one of the faces, as faces are defined in Definition 2.2.5. For example, suppose we agree that the cyclic ordering of edges at each vertex is the clockwise ordering. Then the oriented edge going *up* along the red boundary will turn left and end up part of the pink face; the oriented edge going *down* will turn left and end up part of the green face.

To make this concrete, I will give some of the vertices names:

[image]

I will denote by $e_{uv}$ the oriented edge such that the incidence map $\varphi$ has $\varphi(e_{uv}) = (u,v)$. In other words, $e_{uv}^- = u$ and $e_{uv}^+ = v$.

The "clockwise cyclic ordering" at each vertex means that:

- At vertex $a$, where $E_a = \{e_{ab}, e_{ac}, e_{ad}\}$, we have $s_a(e_{ab}) = e_{ac}$, $s_a(e_{ac}) = e_{ad}$, and $s_a(e_{ad}) = e_{ab}$.
- At vertex $b$, where $E_b = \{e_{ba}, e_{bc}, \dots\}$, we have $s_b(e_{bc}) = e_{ba}$, with $s_b(e_{ba})$ being one of the edges leaving the diagram.
- At vertex $c$, where $E_c = \{e_{ca}, e_{cb}, e_{cd}\}$, we have $s_c(e_{ca}) = e_{cb}$, $s_c(e_{cb}) = e_{cd}$, and $s_c(e_{cd}) = e_{ca}$.
- At vertex $d$, where $E_d = \{e_{da}, e_{dc}, \dots\}$, we have $s_d(e_{da}) = e_{dc}$, and once again $s_d(e_{dc})$ is one of the edges leaving the diagram.

So if we try to find the face containing edge $e_{ac}$, we want the next edge to be $s_c(\overline{e_{ac}})$ by Definition 2.2.5; $\overline{e_{ac}} = e_{ca}$ and $s_c(e_{ca}) = e_{cb}$. The edge after $e_{cb}$ is $s_b(\overline{e_{cb}}) = s_b(e_{bc}) = e_{ba}$. The edge after $e_{ba}$ is $s_a(\overline{e_{ba}}) = s_a(e_{ab}) = e_{ac}$. The equivalence class of $(e_{ac}, e_{cb}, e_{ba})$ is the unique face containing $e_{ac}$, which is the green face.

Similarly, the face containing $e_{ca}$ will end up being the pink face - try it yourself!